# Migrating Lucene HitCollector (2.x) to Collector (3.x)

Tags: lucene

In one of our projects, we use an old Lucene version (2.3.2). I'm now looking at current Lucene versions (3.5.0) and trying to re-write the old code. In the old project, we extended TopFieldDocCollector to do some extra filtering in the collect() method. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the new Collector class however, and I couldn't find a good example.

1) The method setScorer(). How/where do I get a Scorer object from?

2) The method collect(). I guess I need to create my own Collection and store the docIds I'm interested in, correct?

3) When extending TopDocsCollector instead, I'd need to implement a PriorityQueue to use in the constructor, correct? There seems to be no standard implementation for it. But I still need my own Collection to store docIds (or rather, ScoreDocs), and call populateResults after the search is finished?

Overall, it seems like extending Collector is (a lot) easier than extending TopDocsCollector, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5):

1. setScorer() is a hook, the Scorer is passed in by IndexSearcher when it actually does the search. So you basically override this method if you care about scores at all (e.g. saving the passed in Scorer away so you can use it). From its javadocs:

   Called before successive calls to {@link #collect(int)}. Implementations
   that need the score of the current document (passed-in to
   {@link #collect(int)}), should save the passed-in Scorer and call
   scorer.score() when needed.
2. collect() is called for each matching document, passing in the per-segment docid. Note if you need the 'rebased docid' (relative to the entire reader across all of its segments) then you must override setNextReader, saving the docBase, and compute docBase + docid. From Collector javadocs:

   NOTE: The doc that is passed to the collect
    method is relative to the current reader. If your
    collector needs to resolve this to the docID space of the
    Multi*Reader, you must re-base it by recording the
    docBase from the most recent setNextReader call.
3. TopDocsCollector is a base class for TopFieldCollector (sort by field) and TopScoreDocCollector (sort by score). If you are writing a custom collector that sorts by score, then its probably easier to just extend TopScoreDocCollector.

Also: the simplest Collector example is TotalHitCountCollector!

Comment: Thank you. Good to know about setScorer(), I didn't understand that API documentation and thought that I had to create the Scorer myself and pass it in to get scores.